# Ruby / Rails 4 - SyntaxError in UsersController#show

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, variables, syntax, syntax-error

I need fresh eyes to guide me through this syntax error.

Error: SyntaxError in UsersController#show

```
Extracted source (around line #164):

162  <div class="panel panel-default">
163    <h3>STREAM</h3>
164    <%= if @user.microposts.any? %>
165    <h4><%= @user.microposts.count %> Posts</h4>
166     <ol class="microposts">
167     <%= render @microposts %>
```

---

Error: SyntaxError in UsersController#show (Screenshot)

[image: SyntaxError in UsersController#show]

---

Error: View

```
    <!--MICROPOSTS FEED-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <h3>STREAM</h3>
        <%= if @user.microposts.any? %>
            <h4><%= @user.microposts.count %> Posts</h4>
                <ol class="microposts">
                    <%= render @microposts %>
                </ol>
            <%= will_paginate @microposts %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: you don't need an equals on that line: it should be `<%` instead of `<%=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= if @user.microposts.any? %>
```

should be

```
<% if @user.microposts.any? %>
```

nothing to display :P